# Path Finding Algorithm using Polygons/ Polygonal Map Representation

Tags: maps, artificial-intelligence, polygon, path-finding

I'm figuring out a way to find the shortest path given a **source** and **destination**. My map is like of a building's floor plan. And I represented my map using **polygons** like of below:

```
class Polygon(){

    String polygon_name; // describes whether it is a room, or a path, or an untraversable area 

    ArrayList <Coordinates> corners; // describes the coordinates of the corners of the polygon

    ArrayList <Coordinates> center; // describes the center of a polygon/rectangle
}
```

I have a list of all of the polygons, and I cannot figure out how I can implement path finding in this scenario. I have tried A* algorithm before, but using grids or tiles, pretty much the basic example, but I don't know how to use that here because of the polygons.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

[image: sample image]

All of the blue rectangles are the rooms, the black solid filled rectangle is untraversable, and the black unfilled rectangle is a path. I could also safely assume that a room is not a path towards another room, and I could disregard of the entrances towards the room and just uses the **centers** of the room as I already have it. I know all of the corners of the rectangles. And I hope to get the shortest path from the red circle to the other red circle with x.

I'm not totally sure if my map representation is also correct and enough. But is there a way for me to achieve path finding when I already have the polygons?

Comment: I suggest you research what graphs are and how they work. A\* it's a pathfinding algorithm over graphs. Implementing it for a grid is the same as implementing it for "polygons".

Comment: It is not clear how all polygons are connected. For path finding  you need a way to get the neighbors of each node, meaning, which nodes you can access form any give node. Once you have this functionality (for example by implementing a method that returns all neighbors for a give node), you can go ahead and find the path. I recommend starting with simple BFS.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft yes, actually I do think it's possible but it is like what c0der says, it isn't clear about how all the polygons are connected and that's how I'm figuring out to fix.

Comment: @c0der thank you. That's what I thought so too yesterday, and I'm trying to figure out how to change my map representation.
The reason why it was represented like that is because I'm using it for a localization/positioning system, hence, the polygons of the areas are as needed for one's location to be determined.

Thanks for your responses! I do think that my map representation has to be modified, I'm still figuring out a way for a graph to be generated from this point.